# How to code the functionalities similar to SAP B1 SDK using SAP Business One Webclient API?

Tags: client, sapb1

Is it possible to add a control like button, choose from list, edit text etc in any of SAP B1 system form like SO, Invoice etc as we do with SAP B1 SDK UI API, in SAP B1 Web client API? How can we code the functionalities like control addition, itemevent, menu event catching etc we did through UI API, in web client API? I didn't see any documentation regarding this in any SAP help or forums? Did B1 started to provide features for these in SAP B1 web client yet?

Searched for online help regarding this sytem form modification and event catching in web client and didnt find any.

Comment: I don't think this has been released yet, but "web client extensibility" is on the B1 'roadmap'. I don't know the scope or timescale of this.

Comment: an interesting article from Boyum on the subject:   https://www.boyum-solutions.com/blog/detail/sap-business-one-web-client-and-the-use-of-add-ons