Is it possible for a User created custom view in SAP Business One web client?
I am implementing a functionality which was originally developed for SAP Business One SDK desktop client, into the SAP B1 web client using the new
SAP B1 web client UI API extensions package.
I have a UDO (header and detail) and in the detail line on a column , I need to add a lookup form through which I can select records from a table(This should be multi select).
In the desktop addon , we used choosefrom list for this).But in web client, this wont work. So created a UDO associated with the lookup data table and assigned that table as
a linked table to the main UDO detail table column.This creates the lookup. But the problem we face is

multi selection is not possible.
2.Only the Code field from the lookup table gets copied to the detail column,based on the code filed value , we need to populate some other fields on the lines grid.
But there is no event which we can use. There is event called "change" for input control.But not possile to get that event for system form grid.
If the grid is created by us , using the layout, that event can be caught and the functionality can be implemented.

So we are planning to create our own grid for the detail lines, and create a user created form as lookup UI.
How can we do this in web client?
1)  Is it possible to design a view using layout, for custom view which is neither system view nor UDO/UDT and code the events in its controller class?
How can we add that to project and configure?
I didnt find any help topics related to this in UI API extensions link
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_BUSINESS_ONE_WEB_CLIENT/e6ac71d18c7543828bd4463f77d67ff7/12dc43e039dc4b02b693dd4ed91e158c.html?version=10.0_FP_2405
Is it possible to add and use a user created form in web client UI API extension just like we were doing in B1 SDK?
If possible , how and what technology we need to use?
2) If we create our own grid for the UDO detail lines,will the UDO lookup will be there if we assign the column to the lookup table as linked?
3) Also, we need to add custom menus under the main menu of B1 web client? I think that may be possible with JQuery? Any thoughts?
1.Tried with UDT table linked to UDO detail table column

Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77823829/1499294 ?
